# Existing React/Node project - adding AWS authentication

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-amplify

Premise: I'm a newbie, so I'm aware that some of my questions or issues might sound obvious to the more experienced.

My situation is: I have an existing React frontend and Node backend. I need to add authentication to my app, so that I can provide login (and future registration) for my colleagues. We use AWS resources and there is an existing user pool in Cognito.

How do I go about doing this?

I've done some research and everything points me to AWS Amplify, but I've found the existing resources very confusing. Amplify seems to create a new, separate backend when I run `amplify init`, but I need to stick with the existing one.

Basically, all I need is the authentication piece, I don't want to use anything else from Amplify itself.

Apologies in advance if I might have missed something obvious. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this exact situation with the [Amplify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-amplify) library.

You can utilize the `Authenticator` component from `@aws-amplify/ui-react` where the docs are [here](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/components/authenticator).

In the most simple form, it would look like this:

```
import { Authenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";

Amplify.configure(awsExports);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Authenticator>
      {/* Pass app entry as children */}
      {({ signOut, user }) => <Home signOut={signOut} user={user} />}
    </Authenticator>
  );
};

//Object holding AWS auth config
//This is a seperate file which is imported
export const awsExports = {
  Auth: {
    mandatorySignIn: true,
    region: "YOUR REGION",
    userPoolId: "COGNITO_POOL_ID",
    userPoolWebClientId: "COGNITO_CLIENT_ID",
  },
};
```

So in my app, I only use this Authenticator component which does all of the interactions with the cognito pool and nothing else from Amplify. There's a number of different props you can pass into the Authenticator component so certainly review the docs.

Comment: Hey Jlove, thank you so much. Can I ask you: 

- Does this mean I don't have to interact with the backend at all? 
- Do I have to initialise anything from the command line/bash or is it simply a matter of adding the component and setting it up correctly? 

Thank you

Comment: So my backend is entirely serverless AWS so I can't speak to exactly what you'll need for your backend but I can answer this:

All the authenticator component does is authenticate valid users from the Cognito pool and then sets a bunch of JSON web tokens (JWT) into local storage. I then use these as authentication to my API routes. 

Since I use AWS API Gateway, the integration is seamless. Here's some [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-verifying-a-jwt.html) on validating JWT straight from AWS.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help for your specific situation! @AntonioRiccelli

Comment: No, you've been extremely helpful @Jlove. Many thanks :)